# Select unique data based on Single Column from Join Query

Tags: sql, cucm

Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    device.name as device,
    devicepool.name as devicepool,
    device.description AS Phone_Description,
    NumPlan.dNOrPattern as Primary_did,
    applicationuser.name
    FROM applicationuser 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN applicationuserdevicemap
        on applicationuserdevicemap.fkapplicationuser = applicationuser.pkid 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN device 
        on device.pkid =applicationuserdevicemap.fkdevice
    LEFT OUTER JOIN DeviceNumPlanMap 
        on DeviceNumPlanMap.fkDevice=Device.pkid 
    FULL JOIN NumPlan 
        on NumPlan.pkid = DeviceNumPlanMap.fkNumPlan AND NumPlan.dNOrPattern NOT LIKE '%#%'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN devicepool
        on device.fkdevicepool = devicepool.pkid 
    WHERE (DeviceNumPlanMap.NumPlanIndex=1 OR DeviceNumPlanMap.NumPlanIndex IS NULL)
        AND device.name like 'SEP%'
        AND device.description NOT LIKE '%IPCOM%'
        AND applicationuser.name='actuser'
    ORDER BY devicepool.name, NumPlan.dNOrPattern
```

Which results in

```
device          | devicepool| phone_description |   primary_did | name
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
SEPA40CC3956A58 | DBL_Test  | Auto 8964         | 8964          | actuser
SEP00230432ABDC | DP_W00301 | Auto 8968         | 4082600       | actuser
SEP001BD5E86761 | DP_W00301 | SEP001B54520367   | 7001          | actuser
SEP00260B5E1997 | DP_W00301 | Auto 8965         | 8965          | actuser
SEP00175A756654 | DP_W06851 | Dobson,Ronda      |               | actuser
SEP00175A756654 | DP_W06851 | Dobson,Ronda      | 8505998965    | actuser
SEP001B54520367 | DP_WA6201 | SEP001B54520367   |               | actuser
```

I need results with Primaru DID as NULL or blank. This has caused Non-Unique entry in device column with SEP00175A756654 repetaig twice.

So ideally result should be,

```
     device         | devicepool| phone_description |   primary_did | name
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SEPA40CC3956A58 | DBL_Test  | Auto 8964         | 8964          | actuser
    SEP00230432ABDC | DP_W00301 | Auto 8968         | 4082600       | actuser
    SEP001BD5E86761 | DP_W00301 | SEP001B54520367   | 7001          | actuser
    SEP00260B5E1997 | DP_W00301 | Auto 8965         | 8965          | actuser
    SEP00175A756654 | DP_W06851 | Dobson,Ronda      | 8505998965    | actuser
    SEP001B54520367 | DP_WA6201 | SEP001B54520367   |               | actuser
```

I need solution on how to use inner join here. If reason can also be explained.

Comment: can you please formulate the question better? what are you trying to achieve? what is the xpected result on the row with SEP00175A756654?

Comment: @DanielAndré I am looking for only unique set of devices with their corresponding details. Applying Full Outer Join and allowinf null has caused returning multiple results. Updated the expected result.

Comment: `WHERE primary_did IS NOT NULL` ?
However, are you sure you need `OUTER JOINS` everywhere?

Comment: I would say you can't get this done the way you want it to. The problem is not in your joins/query. Each device can be associated to 1 or more primary_did (according to you, nulls count as a valid did) so you will always have 1 or more entries in your result. You could try concating all the primary_did in the same entry

Comment: @schenck nope OUTER JOINS are not needed. I did it when I was failing to get Null values. Will edit it. And the condition you suggested that should be with last condition or at some join.